# CSS3 inifnite animation loop is not working in google chrome 31.0.1650.57

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation

CSS3 Animation is not working. It's need to be working with css3 only.

HTML

```
<b>blink!</b>
```

CSS

```
@-webkit-keyframes datetime-blinker {
    0% { visibility: hidden; }
    100% { visibility: visible; }
}
@-moz-keyframes datetime-blinker {
    0% { visibility: hidden; }
    100% { visibility: visible; }
}
@-o-keyframes datetime-blinker {
    0% { visibility: hidden; }
    100% { visibility: visible; }
}
@keyframes datetime-blinker {
    0% { visibility: hidden; }
    100% { visibility: visible; }
}

b {

    -webkit-animation: datetime-blinker 2s steps(2) 1s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
    -moz-animation:    datetime-blinker 2s steps(2) 1s infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
    -o-animation:      datetime-blinker 2s steps(2) 1s infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
    animation:         datetime-blinker 2s steps(2) 1s infinite; /* IE 10+ */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hYsG8/

Bug tracker:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=324818&thanks=324818&ts=1386002678

Bug is fixed (Google Chrome 33.0.1734.2 canary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've found a bug. I guess Chrome isn't so good at animating boolean values.

You can use opacity as a workaround:

```
@keyframes datetime-blinker {
    0% { opacity: 0.0; }
    49% { opacity: 0.0; }
    50% { opacity: 1.0; }
    100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hYsG8/1/

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a bug. I am myself very bad at interpolating booleans. What is the average of "true" and "false" ?

Comment: It's a bug. Because of first animation cycle, it's works fine.